# How to marshal a struct

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have a c++ library that is used to interface with an rfid scanner. I am trying to use in my c# code but what I am struggling with is getting information about the scanner back in a struct.

This is the C struct and the method that scans for available devices connected to the computer.

```cpp
typedef struct _FEUSB_SCANSEARCH
{
    int             iMask;
    char    cFamilyName[25];
    char    cDeviceName[25];
    char    cInterface[25];
    char    cDeviceID[16];
} FEUSB_SCANSEARCH;

int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FEUSB_Scan(int iScanOpt, FEUSB_SCANSEARCH* pSearchOpt);
```

In my c# code I've created the struct like this

```csharp
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct FEUSB_SCANSEARCH
{
    public int iMask;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 25)]
    public string cFamilyName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 25)]
    public string cDeviceName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 25)]
    public string cInterface;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string cDeviceID;
}

[DllImport("feusb.dll")]
internal static extern int FEUSB_Scan(int iScanOpt, ref FEUSB_SCANSEARCH pSearchOpt);
```

Here is the call to the method that scans connected devices

```csharp
FEUSB_SCANSEARCH scansearch = new FEUSB_SCANSEARCH();
int devHndl = FEUSB_Scan(0x0000000F, ref scansearch);
```

I get a device handle back and I expect the information about the device to be in the struct but it contains only empty strings.
Am I doing the marshalling incorrectly for this struct?

Comment: Use an `IntPtr` in your PInvoke signature. See this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=net-7.0)

Comment: CharSet is wrong, needs to be CharSet.Ansi.  Doubtful that this solves the empty string problem.